# R: Sorting text within a field based on end of line returns \n

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector in which each field represents a string of values separated by an end line return e.g. :

```
x<-c("Banana\nApple\nCherry", "Dog\nCat")
```

Is it possible to sort the text alphabetically within each field so that x becomes:

```
> x
[1] "Apple\nBanana\nCherry" "Cat\nDog"
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be splitting the strings using `strsplit`, sort the individual elements in the `list` and `paste`

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "\n"), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="\n"))
#[1] "Apple\nBanana\nCherry" "Cat\nDog"
```